# Most accurate way to automatically get user's country on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, country, country-codes

This question is perhaps as much about human behaviour as programming.

What is the best way of automatically getting the user's country (**without asking the user**)

It's for a shopping app, so that the correct shopfront gets shown in the app. Imagine, for instance, there are three stores - Japan, US, and France.

There are three ways I can think of doing this:

1. Use a service like http://ipinfo.io/json or http://freegeoip.net/json/ to get the country code.
2. Use the device's carrier code, I'll be able to get the country where they registered their mobile phone.
3. Use their phone's timezone - i.e., they've set their timezone to New York, so their country is US.

Comment: What's your definition of the "user's country"? Is it based on where they are standing at the moment? Is it based on their locale in the Settings app? Something else?

Comment: The user's country in this case should be the same one as their credit card, so they can easily buy thing from the relevant (Japan, US, France) store. They may be American holidaying in Japan, which would complicate things.

Comment: Then getting the user's country from their locale is probably going to give the best results since the locale is typically set to their home country.

Comment: 1. and 3. won't work for your "American holidaying in Japan" case. 2. won't work for phone purchased from US carrier and used by someone in Poland (many people here in Poland actually buy iPhones from US / other countries as they're cheaper).

Answer (score 1):

I would have used the following:

```
NSString *locale = [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier];
```

That will work for the vast majority of people who are in their own country, and haven't set their locale to some random other country.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *countryCode = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];
```

will get you an identifier like e.g. "US" (United States), "ES" (Spain), etc.

Answer (score 1):

use `NSLocale` for fetch country Name

like

```
 NSString *CodeofCountry = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode];
NSString *countryName = [[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode value:CodeofCountry];
NSLog(@" Code:%@ Name:%@",CodeofCountry, countryName);
//Code:IN Name:India
```

Source [Link:](http://code-ios.blogspot.in/2015/03/programatically-finding-current-country.html)

else use `CLLocationManager` to get current location & `CLGeocoder` to perform reverse-geocoding. You can get country name

```
 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    if (locations == nil)
        return;

    self.currentLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:self.currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
    {
        if (placemarks == nil)
            return;

        self.currentLocPlacemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"Current country: %@", [self.currentLocPlacemark country]);
        NSLog(@"Current country code: %@", [self.currentLocPlacemark ISOcountryCode]);
    }];
}
```

else use `NSTimeZone`,

```
 NSLog(@"country Name: %@", [NSTimeZone localTimeZone].name);
 NSLog(@"abbrevationbs %@",[NSTimeZone localTimeZone].abbreviation);
```

Comment: I think the CLLocationManager will pop-up a permission dialogue, which I don't want to bother the user with.

Comment: @cannyboy -- I given the various options based on your choice , select any on options

Comment: How do you plan to get a country from the timezone name or abbreviation? Many countries can be in a given timezone.

Comment: @cannyboy That github link code doesn't use the time zone's name or abbreviation. It uses the time zone's localized name after lots of processing.