# Am I understanding Region Info correctly?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, globalization, regioninfo

So I don't necessarily need geocoding permissions, I don't care what the users city or location is, I just want to get the users country, or even continent. I found this guy in Xamarin documentation

`System.Globalization.RegionInfo`

Which when I test and access `System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.Name` I get back `US`. Which I am in the United States, so that works. But I am beginning to question whether or not this is doing what I think it is. Is `RegionInfo` something I can access to get a users location? The reason I am questioning this is, when I ran my app on iOS simulator on Mac (windows (Xamarin iOS Windows Simulator, not Windows OS) doesn't let you do a custom location for some reason), I had changed the lat/long values to be in Australia. But my value was still `US`. I can chalk that up to being a simulator, perhaps that `RegionInfo` uses some other process and doesn't get affected by the custom lat/long values on simulator. I just want to make sure this is doing what I think it is.

Comment: You're not understanding. Windows iOS Simulator doesn't let you. Sorry poor verbiage maybe. Xamarin does not give you the ability to set a custom location on the iOS Windows Simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RegionInfo is a user configurable value - look in Settings -> General -> Language and Region.

If you want to know the user's physical location, you can

```
1. use GPS
2. ask them
3. try IP geolocation
```

Comment: What about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784543/most-accurate-way-to-automatically-get-users-country-on-ios it looks like they're accessing `NSLocale`. Essentially I just want the country of the user because I want to set a value based on whether or not they're in north america. I really don't want to request access for geolocation just to update a property. Just need a very general location for user that doesn't have to be specific at all.

Comment: That just gets the country name that goes with their locale.  If I flew to Antartica tomorrow, my locale would still be set to US unless I change it.  For your purposes, it may be good enough to just check if their locale is set to US, CA or MX.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I think that's the way to go as well.